# MMQGIS Plugin error in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis-plugins, geocoding, csv, qgis-2, utf-8

I've tried to geocode with MMQGIS Plugin a CSV file with addresses (converted from an Excel file) and I get an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0: invalid  continuation byte
```

[image]

[image]

I've tried to save the CSV file with option UTF-8 but didn't found an option like it:

[image]

How can I handle this?

Comment: Are there perhaps invalid utf-8 characters in the content of the CSV table? I've just tried to save a CSV from Excel and use MMQgis geocode plugins and it works

Answer (score 5):

**Libreoffice calc:**
You can choose the encoding with libreoffice calc:
[image: Edit filter settings]
[image: Encoding for CSV file]

**MS Excel**
Follow: https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16
When saving as, click tools -> Web options -> Encoding -> choose the right encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Open CSV file in Notepad and save as with UTF-8 encoding.

[image]